# JS page with MIME type text.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mime-types

Chrome is giving me the following error

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
```

The file is defiantly a .js file called from the following code

Is there any reason why the file should have the MIME type text/plain? is there any way to change this?

I am working on this locally on my laptop if that makes any difference?

Comment: The mime type is supplied in the tcp headers by the servers, if the server thinks it is text then it sends headers saying it is text/plain. If you own the server you can change your mimetype file to  represent the correct type. Otherwise it is out of your hands. This should not affect your script though, as Chrome said, it interpreted it as script

Comment: You should change it in the registry. use regedit to do it.